# Asp.net core Identity successful login redirecting back to login page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I have a problem where the asp.net identity framework is redirecting the user back to the login page after they have logged in successfully.

This is using the standard Asp.net Core Identity. It is the version 2.1.1. The scaffolding that generates the razor pages. Not sure if that is significant.

I know the user is successfully logging in because I get the log message

> ...Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.LoginModel: Information: User logged in.

But then it redirects straight back to the login page.

If I use fiddler I can see that there is a cookie on the request so it all looks good from that perspective.

```
.AspNetCore.Identity.Application=CfDJ8KJxkuir9ZJIjFLCU2bzm9n6X...
```

So I guess the middleware that is handling the authentication but not accepting the cookie?

If I could see what the actual middleware for the auth was doing I might have an idea but I can't find it.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In order to get the ASP.NET Core pipeline to recognise that a user is signed in, a call to `UseAuthentication` is required in the `Configure` method of your `Startup` class, like so:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseMvc(); // Order here is important (explained below).
```

Using the Cookies authentication scheme, the use of `UseAuthentication` loosely performs the following:

- Reads the content of the `.AspNetCore.Identity.Application` cookie from the request, which represents the identity of the user making the request.
- Populates the `User` property of `HttpContext` with a `ClaimsPrincipal` that represents said user.

This is a simplified explanation of what happens, but it highlights the important job that the authentication middleware performs. Without the authentication middleware, the `.AspNetCore.Identity.Application` will not be used for authenticating the user and therefore the user will not be authenticated. In your case, although the user has signed in (i.e. the cookie is being set), the pipeline middleware (e.g. MVC) does not see this user (i.e. the cookie is not being read) and so sees an unauthenticated request and redirects again for login.

Given that the authentication middleware reads the cookie and subsequently populates the `ClaimsPrincipal`, it should be clear that the `UseAuthentication` call must also be *before* the `UseMvc` call in order for this to occur in the correct order. Otherwise, the MVC middleware runs before the Authentication middleware and will not be working with a populated `ClaimsPrincipal`.

> Why is it failing to login if you don't add the middleware that handles the login?!?

The middleware doesn't handle the login - it handles the authentication process. The user *has* logged in, which is confirmed by the presence of the `.AspNetCore.Identity.Application` cookie. What is failing here is the reading of said cookie.

Answer (score 21):

Note that the order is IMPORTANT.  I had these reversed and experienced the exact same problem the original poster experienced.  Hours wasted before I figured this out...

```
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();
```

Answer (score 4):

In addition to @Kirk Larkin answer if you use .net core 3 (in this time is preview version)

put your "app.UseEndpoints" in startup.cs to end of the code block.

for example it should be in this order

```
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseMvc();

This was already in my code.However I was facing same issue.
But the problem was with the Chrome browser on my case.It was working with other browser like mozilla.
It starts to work on Chrome too, after i cleared all the cookies and cashes.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do a couple of these solutions.

First, I had app.UseAuthentication(); and app.UseAuthorization(); in the incorrect order.

Second, After making the adjustment to startup.cs I was still experiencing the same problem. Doing a hard refresh a few times fixed it (can also just clear the browser cache).

Answer (score 1):

Another gotcha that I fought with for a number of hours is that I had the following code in my Program file.

```
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to the 
default policy
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});
```

This had the impact of causing a recursive call to the ReturnUrl and ended up with the following error.  Simply removing this code block rectified the issue for me.

[image: RecursiveReturnUrl]

Comment: Don't do this; that bit is there for a reason and removing it will reduce security. The real problem is the target page is probably missing an `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I tried many suggestions and finally what worked for me was:
First, in your ConfigureServices class within "Startup.cs" add this

```
services.AddMvc().AddMvcOptions(Mvcoption => {
            Mvcoption.EnableEndpointRouting = false;
        });
```

The above code should come after this:

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddCookie(options =>
                {
                    options.LoginPath = "/Home/Login";


                });
```

Just in case you don't have the above two codes, try including them in your mvc application. Then you can go ahead and add these in your Configure method.

```
app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseMvc();
```

Hope it works now.

Happy coding!