# asp.net core 2.2 redirects to login after successful sign in

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

- I updated my visual studio 2017 to the latest 15.9.5.

I have created an out the box asp.net core 2.2 web mvc project with individual user accounts. I set the db up (update-database from package manager console) and ran the site in IIS Express. All good to this point. Registered a user and could sign in.

Deployed the app to IIS - running as an application under the default site and its stuck redirecting back to the login page after successfully signing in.
(All deployed correctly - app = no managed code)

So I commit the project to a bit bucket repo and ask a friend to try this on their machine. With IIS Express and the database I have given him it's stuck - redirecting back to login after successful sign.

No custom code - all scaffolded code.

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
            .AddDefaultUI(UIFramework.Bootstrap4)
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

}

Comment: How did you configure database and connectionstring when deloying to iis? Run your project from your own Vs, will you redirecting back to login? For your fridend site, is there any output in the vs output windows while logining?

Comment: First it was a trusted connection. Then I added a user and granted that user sysadmin rights.

Comment: Try to run your web app in IIS under your current domain account

Comment: I ran it under the network service account.What does not make sense, another another machine running in visual studio 2017 - iis express it gives the same behaviour.

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51602203/asp-net-core-identity-successful-login-redirecting-back-to-login-page/62032929#62032929) out, it may actually be of help. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

I think EF can't access your database. Make sure that database is reachable by using connection settings from DefaultConnection. Set debugger into login method and check what is returned from UserManager methods.

Comment: I checked that - the user manager connects and finds the user. I also added the developer environment value to the web.config. The user is signed in successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I run following on my mac and issue resolved.

```
sudo dotnet dev-certs https --trust;
```

Comment: Thanks @venu - I did an update-packages and it magically started to work however I don't that's the issue. Will try this out. I am running windows 10 x64 with vs 2017 professional 15.9.5