# Azure authorization - let unauthenticated user call api

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-active-directory

I have .net core rest api with azure. I have configured azure authentication for my rest api. I want to add second way to login by passing token in headers. On azure I changed configuration so now application is set to "allow unauthenticated access". I also added middleware logic to check if token is present in headers, then validate token, add user to http context. Locally it works perfectly, but when I deploy it to azure I have problem. No matter what request I send, with or without token I'm always getting redirected to login page. Is it possible to change this ? I would like to validate token on backend and grant access to application based of token passed in headers.
As identity provider I use Microsoft.

[image: azure settings screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Please check if any of below are causes :

1. Please check if the url present in authentication redirect url for azure ad is same as the one present in the code request url /redirect url.
2. The user is confirmed by the presence of the .AspNetCore.Identity.Application cookie .Authentication middleware reads the cookie and subsequently populates the ClaimsPrincipal.For this the `app.UseAuthentication` call must  be before the UseMvc call.So make sure to use app.UseAuthentication() before app.UseMvc() or app.UseAuthorization() and app.UseEndpoints(…).[Use cookie authentication without ASP.NET Core Identity | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-6.0)
3. If everything is working locally ,try to set your login redirect to
   `~/.auth/login/aad?post_login_redirect_url=/api/protectedcontroller/action`, and the user will be redirected to this page if login is successful .See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34348271/how-to-set-azure-authentication-custom-login-return-url)
4. Also check if you have configured scope for azure ad in code after exposing the api  and if you  need to inject token header to retrieve token. Have a look at this  [Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-auth-aad?pivots=platform-windows#configure-app-service-to-return-a-usable-access-token)

Please check these **References:**

1. [Azure Apps EasyAuth claims with .NET Core - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42260708/azure-apps-easyauth-claims-with-net-core/42270669#42270669)
2. [.NET Core app with Azure App Service Authentication - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49151961/net-core-app-with-azure-app-service-authentication)
3. [Asp.net core Identity successful login redirecting back to login page - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51602203/asp-net-core-identity-successful-login-redirecting-back-to-login-page)